# animationTypeForReplace in React Native is not responding with 'pop' effect

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

**I want to give pop animation to screens in my app when user navigate from one to another.**

so I implemented below code :

**FoodDetailScreen.navigationOptions = ()=>{
    return {
        header : null,
        animationTypeForReplace : 'pop',
        animationEnabled : true
    }
}**

But still its pushing the screen as usual and not giving Pop animation.

Reference URL : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/stack-navigator

Comment: As the docs say, it's for "The type of animation to use when this screen replaces another screen". So it'll only work for replace, not when user navigates from one screen to another.